# php to json group array

Tags: php, mysql, json, grouping

My goal is list singers and click singer show singers songs.
This is my php

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "123456";
    $database = "database";
    $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database, $con);
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
    $sql = "SELECT a.singername,b.songname,b.songembeded from singers a,songs b where a.singerid=b.singerid";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
    $records = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    utf8_encode($records);
    echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

This is my json output:

```
[{"singername":"singerA", "songname":"songA", "songembeded":"https://www.youtube.com"},{"singername":"singerA", "songname":"songB", "songembeded":"https://www.youtube.com"}, "singername":"singerB","songname":"songX", "songembeded":"https://www.youtube.com"}]
```

I want to make like a group singers and their songs:

```
["singername":"singerA","songs": {"songname":"songA","songembeded":"https://www.youtube.com"},{"songname":"songB","songembeded":"https://www.youtube.com"},
"singername":"singerB","songs": {"songname":"songX","songembeded":"https://www.youtube.com"}]
```

Comment: The grouping you want would have duplicate keys.

Comment: We just don't do it like this any more

Comment: my singer table  singerid,singername

Comment: my songs table songid,songname,songembeded,singerid...

Comment: relation two table  singerid

Comment: i want to make iOS app..   first tableview will show singers list, second table will show selected singers songs, at last table will show songs video... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query a little:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.singername,b.songname,b.songembeded from singers a,songs b where a.singerid=b.singerid ORDER BY a.singername";
```

so replace you loop:

```
$records = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
```

with this one

```
$records = array();
$songs= array();
$singername='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if ($singername!='' && $singername!=$row['singername']) {
       $records[]= array("singername"=>$singername,"songs"=>$songs);
       $songs = array();
    }
    $songs[] = array('songname'=>$row['songname'],'songembeded'=>$row['songembeded']);
    $singername=$row['singername'];
}
$records[]= array("singername"=>$singername,"songs"=>$songs);
```